# Account for small but significant categories in model

Tags: machine-learning, cart, categorical-encoding, many-categories

I want to model participation to a campaign.

I have ~200 variables for ~100k observations.

Many variables are categorical and I often found high participation rates in smaller categories, for example consider these numbers of observations for an age variable:

```
  (0,10]  (10,20]  (20,30]  (30,40]  (40,50]  (50,60]  (60,70]  (70,80]
   50000     2000     1000      500      100       25      10         1
```

Say individuals from the `(30,40]` brackets are twice likely to participate.

They're a small fraction from my sample but I'd rather remove this info or lose it in the noise, especially as many if not most of my variables have a similar relationship with my target.

How do I decide how to group the data ? (should I put 50+ together, 40+ ? should I choose a model that take this decision for me ?).

And then what type of models will be suited for this analysis ? My intuition says regression trees will be more "respectful of the minorities", but I don't trust my intuition that much :).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the age variable as continuous, by taking the middle/mean of your age bracket as value. I would still look to remove the observation from the 70-80 bracket since you will probably get more noise than signal from one such value.